# Is there a way to exit the code in the setup tag with the Vue-Composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import router from '@/router';
import { useMainStore } from '@/stores/main';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const mainStore = useMainStore()
const x = ref<object| undefined>();

if (!mainStore.x) {
    router.replace('/')
} else {
    x.value = mainStore.x
}

if (!x.value) {
    router.replace('/')
} else {
    console.log(x.value.location);
}

function fun() {
    if (!x.value) {
        router.replace('/')
        return 5;
    }
    return x.value.location;
}
</script>
```

I essentially want to know that if there is a way exit this sfc if mainStore.x is undefined. Then for the remainder of the code, x.value will not be undefined so I do not need to check if its undefined each time I want to use it.

I use router.replace to change to a different sfc so x.value will never be undefined in this sfc.

Comment: What do you mean by *"exit"*? If you want to change route based on some store prop, use `beforeEach` on router, check the store and return the appropriate route.

Comment: I could use beforeEach, however I will still get typescript errors within the sfc, and will still have to check it is not null before using it anywhere in the sfc.

Comment: By "exit", I mean that the type of the variable will not be null for the rest of the file. For example in a function, you can return if null, then for the rest of the function we know the variable is not null. Is there a way to assert not null, or throw an error if null?

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this, is to wrap the rest of your code in an else block, and check not-null at the start of each function (return if null).

Also if you need that variable in your template, use v-if="!variable", for some reason :if doesn't work for me.